# cx_Oracle connection fails with 'DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library'

Tags: python, windows, oracle, cx-oracle

Problem use connection oracle to python source, oracle now is worked to other language php (oci)

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\xampp\htdocs\pyoracle\testConnectionOracle.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('xxx','xxx', dsn_tns,'UTF-8')
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "failed to get message for Windows Error 126". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help
```

Code:

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('192.168.1.217', '1521', service_name='xx') 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('xx','xx', dsn_tns,'UTF-8')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('select * from database.table')
for row in c:
    print (row[0], '-', row[1])
conn.close()
```

Comment: is `ORACLE_HOME` set in your `PATH`?

Comment: If Oracle Instant Client is being used, then you wouldn't (and shouldn't) set ORACLE_HOME.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: try the latest version of cx_Oracle see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  This version (which was renamed [python-oracledb](https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/)) doesn't need Instant Client so the installation is easier.

Here are the [cx_Oracle Windows installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows), which you probably found from the error message you quoted.

I will assume (i) you actually have 64-bit Oracle client libraries 11g or later, and also (ii) have the required VS Redistributable as mentioned in the install instructions.  Then a simple thing to try is to add this to the top of your script:

```
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\oracle\instantclient_19_6")
```

Use the actual path to your client libraries.

PHP may be 32-bit and using 32-bit Oracle libraries. If so, because you have a 64-bit Python, then you will need to install 64-bit Instant Client or install 32-bit Python. (Note PHP OCI8 doesn't have an equivalent call to `init_oracle_client()`. In PHP you need to make sure the Oracle Client libraries are in the system search path e.g. PATH before the PHP process starts.)